# How do I push a parameter into a multiple nested array/object structure?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, conditional-statements

given the following database

```
DB = [
    {
        genre:'thriller', 
        movies:[
            {
                title:'the usual suspects', release_date:1999
            }
        ]},
        {
        genre:'commedy', 
        movies:[
            {
                title:'pinapple express', release_date:2008
            }
        ]}
]
```

I want to check if genres and movies are existing in it and add if not.

I have this code so far. The only thing that is missing, is to push a (new) movie at the index of the genre, if the movie is not there (commented out and bold).

```
var moviesDB = function (array, genre, movie) {
    var x = []

    for (var i = 0; i < DB.length; i++) {
        x.push(DB[i].genre);
    }

    if(x.includes(genre) == false) {
        DB.push({genre: genre, movies: []});    
    } else {
        console.log("genre already here")
    }

    var y = []

    for (var i = 0; i < DB.length; i++) {
        DB[i].movies.forEach (function (object){
            y.push(object.title)
        })
    }

    if(y.includes(movie) == false) {
        //**push movie into the existing object.**
    } else {
        return `the movie the ${movie} is already in the database!`
    }

    return DB;
}
```

Sp `moviesDB = function (DB, "drama", "A drama movie")`should add a new genre-object (drama) and in the movies array a new object with "A drama movie" title. And  `moviesDB = function (DB, "commedy", "Scary movie")` should just add a new object with the movie title in the existing commedy genre-object.

```js
DB = [
    {
        genre:'thriller', 
        movies:[
            {
                title:'the usual suspects', release_date:1999
            }
        ]},
        {
        genre:'commedy', 
        movies:[
            {
                title:'pinapple express', release_date:2008
            }
        ]}
]


var moviesDB = function (array, genre, movie) {
    var x = []

    for (var i = 0; i < DB.length; i++) {
        x.push(DB[i].genre);
    }

    if(x.includes(genre) == false) {
        DB.push({genre: genre, movies: []});    
    } else {
        console.log("genre already here")
    }

    var y = []

    for (var i = 0; i < DB.length; i++) {
        DB[i].movies.forEach (function (object){
            y.push(object.title)
        })
    }

    if(y.includes(movie) == false) {
        //**push movie into the existing object.**
    } else {
        return `the movie the ${movie} is already in the database!`
    }

    return DB;
}
console.log(moviesDB(DB, "drama", "A drama movie"))
```

Comment: If possible keep the code structure and only help me with the one line highlighted since this is the level and techniques I currently have.

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57927792/edit) then `[<>]` to create a [mcve] - it is very hard to guess how you call your moviesDB and it looks like you loop where you shouldn't

Comment: The parameter `array` is never used in your function. Imo all occurrences of `DB` in that function should be replaced with `array`, or the `array` parameter has to be removed.

Comment: @3limin4t0r sure, I use it when I call the function

Comment: Yes, you pass it to the function, but never actually use it in the function. Try replacing `moviesDB(DB, "drama", "A drama movie")` with `moviesDB(undefined, "drama", "A drama movie")` and you will see that you produce the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected, add below to code to the commented section

```
if(y.includes(movie) == false) {
        //**push movie into the existing object.**
      DB.forEach(v => {
        if(v.genre === genre){
          v.movies.push({title: movie})
        }
      })
    }
```

**Explanation:** If movie is existing object, loop DB array and check for genre and push to movies list

Working code for reference

```js
DB = [
    {
        genre:'thriller', 
        movies:[
            {
                title:'the usual suspects', release_date:1999
            }
        ]},
        {
        genre:'commedy', 
        movies:[
            {
                title:'pinapple express', release_date:2008
            }
        ]}
]


var moviesDB = function(DB, genre, movie) {
movie = typeof movie === 'object'? movie.title : movie; // to check whether movie parameter is string or object
    var x = []

    for (var i = 0; i < DB.length; i++) {
        x.push(DB[i].genre);
    }

    if(x.includes(genre) == false) {
        DB.push({genre: genre, movies: []});    
    } else {
        console.log("genre already here")
    }

    var y = []

    for (var i = 0; i < DB.length; i++) {
        DB[i].movies.forEach (function (object){
            y.push(object.title)
        })
    }

    if(y.includes(movie) == false) {
        //**push movie into the existing object.**
      DB.forEach(function(object) {
    if(object.genre === genre){
      object.movies.push({title: movie})
    }
  })
} else {
        return `the movie the ${movie} is already in the database!`
    }

    return DB;
}

console.log(moviesDB(DB, "drama", "A drama movie"))
console.log(moviesDB(DB, "commedy", "Scary movie"))
console.log(moviesDB(DB, 'commedy', 'pinapple express'))
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/oNvymeB?editors=1010

Comment: for some reason your code does not work when I run terminal tests. E.G. 
1) #test2
       moviesDB should be a {genre:'commedy', title:'pinapple express'}:
     AssertionError: expected { title: 'pinapple express' } to equal 'pinapple express'

Comment: please share sample input for which it failed

Comment: moviesDB(DB, 'commedy', {title:'pinapple express'})

Comment: moviesDB(DB, 'commedy', {title:'Banana'})

2) #test3
       moviesDB should be a {title:'Banana'}:
     AssertionError: expected { title: 'Banana' } to equal 'Banana'
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/b7exercise1.test.js:20:16)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)

Comment: As a reference ... @Calvins code is running but he uses another structure then I do and then you proposed and I'd love to stick to my structure which I understand

Comment: so movieTitle can be passed as 'pinapple express' or {title:'pinapple express'} while calling movieDB method?

Comment: Rather the latter as it seems

Comment: updated code , added this line , now it should work for both movie = typeof movie === 'object'? movie.title : movie; // to check whether movie parameter is string or object

Comment: works. and how would it look like if you assume that only the second version {title:'pinapple express'}  is added? I don't understand the line

Comment: Also is there a way to write out this function in a more traditional way? I don't understand => style functions yet.

DB.forEach(v => {
        if(v.genre === genre){
          v.movies.push({title: movie})
        }
      })

Comment: it is ternary operator , shortcut of if statement, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: @Stephan-thecurious, it is arrow function shortcut of function statement, anyway i ahve updated code - DB.forEach(function(object) {
        if(object.genre === genre){
          object.movies.push({title: movie})
        }
      })
    }

Comment: THX: can you modify this so that it assumes an object instead of checking?

movie = typeof movie === 'object'? movie.title : movie; // to check whether movie parameter is string or object

Comment: if it is always object , then simply use movie = movie.title

Comment: THX ... but how does Calvin belwo does it without the modification?

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this problem, with the code below, that is simple to understand and readable, without code that can be "weird" to someone that doesn't have much experience yet.

Well, you can firstly loop the objects to check each `genre`, if one of them matches the one that you are trying to insert, then "select" the object that holds this genre. If no genre is found, then create a new object.

After having the object that holds the genre (the new one or one that already exists), then start looping through movies of this genre, do the same check you did for genre, except that if you found the movie `title`, then just return something and dont push the movie to the `movies` list. If not found, then push it.

Look below, see if the code is understandeable (I added some comments inside code)

```js
let DB = [{
    genre: 'thriller',
    movies: [{
      title: 'the usual suspects',
      release_date: 1999
    }]
  },
  {
    genre: 'commedy',
    movies: [{
      title: 'pinapple express',
      release_date: 2008
    }]
  }
]

var moviesDB = function(array, genre, movie) {
  let selectedObj = null;

  //let's look for the genre, if exists
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let obj = array[i];
    if (obj.genre == genre) {
      selectedObj = obj;
      break
    }
  }

  //if the genre is not found, create a new one
  if (selectedObj == null) {
    selectedObj = {
      genre: genre,
      movies: []
    }
    array.push(selectedObj)
  }

  //let's check the movies of this genre
  let movies = selectedObj.movies
  for (let i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
    let mv = movies[i];
    if (mv.title == movie.title) {
      return "The movie '" + movie.title + "' already exists in genre: " + genre;
    }
  }

  //if the code didn't returned above, them insert new movie
  selectedObj.movies.push(movie)
  return "The movie '" + movie.title + "' was successfully inserted into genre: " + genre;
}


console.log(moviesDB(DB, 'commedy', {
  title: 'newOne',
  release_date: 2010
}))
console.log(moviesDB(DB, 'commedy', {
  title: 'pinapple express',
  release_date: 2008
}))

console.log(DB)
```

Comment: Is it somehow possible without the break? Don't know the concept of this currently

Comment: `break` is just to stop the for loop to continue... since you already found the object with the genre, there's no need to keep the looping going, so break it to stop and go ahead with the rest of the code, (in bigger for loops, it helps in performace, imagine 1000 objects, if you found the object you need in the second position, why to loop it more 998 times? Got it?)

Comment: yes, it would. (or not if you have two objects with exact same genre, the one would overwrite the other, but I don't think it is the case here)

Comment: Your code works but it's a bit more advanced than I currently can apply.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to figure out if the genre already exists, and then either push the new genre, or figure out if the new title already exists in the existing genre and add it.

```js
const DB = [
    {
        genre:'thriller', 
        movies:[
            {
                title:'the usual suspects', release_date:1999
            }
        ]},
        {
        genre:'comedy', 
        movies:[
            {
                title:'pinapple express', release_date:2008
            }
        ]}
];


const addMovie = (db, genre, movie) => {
  const genreObject = db.find((dataItem) => dataItem.genre === genre);
  if(!genreObject){
    db.push({genre: genre, movies: [movie]});
  } else {
    const movieTitles = genreObject.movies.map((movie) => movie.title);
    if(!movieTitles.includes(movie.title)){
      genreObject.movies.push(movie);
    }
  }
}

addMovie(DB, "drama", {title: "pretend drama"});
addMovie(DB, "comedy", {title: "pretend comedy"});

console.log(DB);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the problem, this is the simplest way I came up with. The code is pretty self-explanatory and I have added comments to it

```js
const Database = [
  {
    genre: 'thriller',
    movies: [
      {
        title: 'the usual suspects',
        release_date: 1999
            }
        ]
  },
  {
    genre: 'comedy',
    movies: [
      {
        title: 'pinapple express',
        release_date: 2008
            }
        ]
  }
]

const findOrAddMovie = ({ genre, movie }) => {
  // check if genre exists
  const hasGenre = Database.find(i => i.genre && i.genre === genre);

  if (!hasGenre) {
    // if genre doesn't exists, add it
    Database.push({ genre, movies: [] });
  }

  // map over the database 
  Database.map(item => {
    // only look in the genre we passed in 
    if (item.genre && item.genre === genre) {
      // find the movie by its title
      const thisMovie = item.movies.find(m => m.title === movie.title);

      if (!thisMovie) {
        // add movie if it doesn't exists
        // doing this here, so as to prevent 
        // another "map" call on "Database"
        item.movies.push({ ...movie });
      }
    }
  });

  //
  // just for references
  // 
  return Database;
}

console.log(
  findOrAddMovie({
    genre: "comedy",
    movie: {
      title: 'added movie 1',
      release_date: 2008
    }
  })
);
console.log(
  findOrAddMovie({
    genre: "thriller",
    movie: {
      title: 'added movie 2',
      release_date: 2008
    }
  })
);
console.log(
  findOrAddMovie({
    genre: "mygenre",
    movie: {
      title: 'added movie with genre',
      release_date: 2008
    }
  })
);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is very elegant but likely way over OP's head.

Answer (score -1):

You need to simplify your DB - code and DB van be vastly simplified

```js
let DB = {
  'thriller': {
    movies: [{
      title: 'the usual suspects',
      release_date: 1999
    }]
  },
  'comedy': {
    movies: [{
      title: 'pinapple express',
      release_date: 2008
    }]
  }
}

var moviesDB = function(array, genre, title, release) {
  let g = DB[genre]
  if (!g) DB[genre] = {
    "movies": []
  }
  movies = DB[genre].movies
  const movie = {
    "title": title,
    "release_date": release
  }
  let obj = movies.find(o => o.title === movie.title);
  if (!obj) {
    movies.push(movie)
  } else {
    return `the movie the ${movie.title} is already in the database!`
  }  
  return DB;
}
moviesDB(DB, "drama", "A drama movie", 2019)
moviesDB(DB, "drama", "A drama movie", 2019)
moviesDB(DB, "thriller", "A thriller", 2019)
console.log(DB)
```

Comment: I don't think that simplifying the DB is an option a lot of times.

Comment: So because you do not think so, my working and improved solution is voted down?

Comment: Yes. That would be it.